# Difference Between Firestore Set with {merge: true} and Update

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In **Cloud Firestore** there are three write operations:

1. `add()`
2. `set()`
3. `update()`

In the docs it says that using `set(object, { merge: true })` will merge the given object with the existing document.

The same happens when you use `update(object)`... so what is the difference? It seems strange that google would duplicate functionality like this.

Answer (score 616, accepted):

The way I understood the difference:

- `set` without `merge` will overwrite a document or create it if it doesn't exist yet
- `set` with `merge` will update fields in the document or create it if it doesn't exists
- `update` will update fields but will fail if the document doesn't exist
- `create` will create the document but fail if the document already exists

There's also a difference in the kind of data you provide to `set` and `update`.

For `set` you always have to provide document-shaped data:

```
set(
  {a: {b: {c: true}}},
  {merge: true}
)
```

With `update` you can also use field paths for updating nested values:

```
update({
  'a.b.c': true
})
```

Comment: but where have you found `create` method in the API?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.8.x/DocumentReference#create for node.js. It seems the web API doesn't have that method. Wasn't sure which platform you are on :)

Comment: Another distinction you can mention is that `set` operates on document-shaped data, where `update` takes field path and value pairs. This means you can make changes to deeply nested values with `update` that are more cumbersome with `set`. For example: `set({a: {b: {c: true}}}, {merge: true})` vs `update('a.b.c', true)`.

Comment: If I want to update a value in a document, It makes sense that I want to update documents that already exists, so I think set + mergeall is not that usefull because it will creat it the document does not exists

Comment: If data you provide to the set command has a field which is null, will it set the field to null if it is already present in the database or will it leave it alone?

Comment: why they make different behavior for `set` and `update`, this is so confusing, and they even didn't clarify this on the doc.

Comment: set with merge option will overwrite the field no matter what. However update will be ignored if this is not the last update. For Example if you trigger the update action on an offline device, and get back online 3 days later.

Comment: Will update throw an error if the document does not exist?

Comment: Does this work for subcollections? I am doing the following: ` await admin.firestore().collection('households').doc(hhid).collection('currentMembers').doc(uid).set({
                joinedDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            }, {
                merge: true,
            }); `

Comment: Now we just need a better way of updating arrays of objects. The current SDK heavily encurages objects, since they are clearly the easiest to update without fear of overwriting anything.

Comment: Beware that adding `{merge:true}` as an option for `update` (as opposed to `set`) appears to ignore the constraint that the document must exist!

Comment: How about when the field does not exist for update operation? What will happen?

Comment: Note that if you need to use a dynamic variable in updateDoc() you have to wrap the entire thing in brackets and then in back ticks. E.g  update({
  [\`a.${b}.c\`]: true
})   In this case "a" and "c" are static fields in the database and "b" is dynamically created key that is passed in during the call. 

Got it from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72247881/11058429

Comment: Re-initialise DocumentReference if you want to add new item  otherwise it will keep on updating last added documen. Re-initalisation creates new documentid

Answer (score 135):

Another difference (extending Scarygami's answer) between "set with merge" and "update", is when working with a nested values.

if you have a document structured like this:

```
 {
   "friends": {
     "friend-uid-1": true,
     "friend-uid-2": true,
   }
 }
```

and want to add `{"friend-uid-3" : true}`

using this:

`db.collection('users').doc('random-id').set({
  "friends": {
    "friend-uid-3": true
  }
},{merge:true})`

will result in this data:

```
 {
   "friends": {
     "friend-uid-1": true,
     "friend-uid-2": true,
     "friend-uid-3": true
   }
 }
```

however `update` using this:

`db.collection('users').doc('random-id').update({
  "friends": {
    "friend-uid-3": true
  }
})`

will result in this data:

```
 `{
   "friends": {
     "friend-uid-3": true
   }
 }`
```

Comment: Have you tried testing this yourself? There is a section in the documentation: "To update some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document, use the update() method..."[link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data)

Comment: yes I have tested this. It was a few weeks ago, but I am positive I came out with the result I wrote. I searched up why it didn't work as expected etc. I will test it out now.

Comment: I figured it out. I only tried this with an array before. Where I wanted to add an object to the array, and everything got overwritten for that array. It does not work with fields containing an array... it does stand it docs.

Comment: Just got to the same conclusion after tests. I hope they will add an option that has the same effect as `{ merge: true }` to the update function.

Comment: Helped me a lot, I was having troubles updating a map inside firestore and **set** with **merge: true** worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: To avoid overwriting data in nested fields (as in the answer above) when using `update`, you can use [dot notation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).  The overwrite behavior of `update` is different if you do/don't use dot notation.

Answer (score 24):

Per docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects

Dot notation allows you to update a single nested field without overwriting other nested field. If you update a nested field without dot notation, you will overwrite the entire map field.

As stated above, this replaces entire friends structure.

```
db.collection('users').doc('random-id').update({
    "friends": {
        "friend-uid-3": true
    }
})
```

This does not.

```
db.collection('users').doc('random-id').update({
    "friends.friend-uid-3": true
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Further adding on to the answers above, if you **want to delete** nested fields in a map then you may want to use `update` or `set` depending on your use case.

If you start with the following and want to remove all profile entries other than `"user1"` then you have two options.

```json
{
  "users": {
    "profiles": {
      "user1": ...,
      "user2": ...
    }
  }
```

#### Update

This will overwrite `profiles` with whatever is provided

```js
update({
  'users.profiles': { 'user1': ... }
})
```

#### Set

This will merge the deletes into the existing profiles,
leaving whatever wasn't deleted

```js
set({
  users: {
    profiles: {
      'user2': FieldValue.delete(),
      'user3': FieldValue.delete(),
      ...
    }
  }
}, { merge: true })
```

This only applies to `Map`s because both `set` and `update` will overwrite arrays unless you explicitly use the [array-specific operators such as `arrayUnion`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Answer (score 0):

Scarygami answer holds true for firebase version 9 as well. Small changes should be considered though:

- use `setDoc` instead of `set`. For example, instead of using `db.collection('users').doc('random-id').set({ 'admin': true });`, use `setDoc(doc(db, 'users', 'random-id'), { "admin": true })`
- use `updateDoc` instead of `update`. For example, instead of using `db.collection('users').doc( random-id').update({"age": 27})`, use  `await updateDoc(doc(db, 'users', 'random-id'), { "age": 27})`

Answer (score 0):

Both `set` with `{merge: true}` and `update` are used for modifying documents in Firestore, but they have different behaviors and use-cases:

#### `set` with `{merge: true}`

When you use `set` with the `{merge: true}` option, the fields you specify are merged into the existing document. If the document doesn't exist, a new document is created with the specified fields.

- **Creates a document if it doesn't exist**: This is useful for upsert-like operations.
- **Overwrites specific fields**: Only the fields you specify in the `set` operation will be overwritten; other fields will remain untouched.
- **Can add new fields**: If you specify fields that don't currently exist in the document, they will be created.

Example:

```js
const docRef = firestore.collection('users').doc('user1');
await docRef.set({
  name: "John",
  age: 30
}, { merge: true });
```

#### `update`

The `update` operation updates the values of specific fields in an existing document. Unlike `set`, it will not create a new document if the document doesn't already exist; you'll get an error instead.

- **Doesn't create a new document**: Requires the document to already exist.
- **Field-level updates**: You can update nested fields using "dot notation."
- **No addition of new fields**: Unlike `set` with `{merge: true}`, which can add fields if they do not exist, `update` requires the fields to exist (although you can update nested fields).

Example:

```js
const docRef = firestore.collection('users').doc('user1');
await docRef.update({
  "address.city": "San Francisco"
});
```

#### Summary

- **`set` with `{merge: true}`**: Good for upsert-like operations. Creates the document if it doesn't exist and merges fields. Can add fields that don't currently exist in the document.
- **`update`**: Only for updating existing documents. Updates can be applied to nested fields. Will error out if the document or fields don't exist.

Choose the one that best fits your use-case.