# When to use update over set in Google Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

When should I use `update()` over `set()`? With `set()` and `merge : true`, I can do exact the same thing as `update()` and it is guaranteed it will not fail, while `update()` will fail if the document does not exist.

Comment: You question have already been answered in this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46600599/7674708