# How to avoid index in firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a database in firestore and loaded the test data successfully. But later I noticed that some data is missing in database. I found that when I load the same records with a different value for some fields the old record is replaced with the new record. I feel like this is the issue in the database design. I need to collect and save all the records even if it is a duplicate records at entire records level.

Could you please let me know how to do this ?

```
private void exportToFireStore() {
    // Access a Cloud Firestore instance from your Activity
    final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    /*  ----------------_-------Collection delete is not supported-----------------------
        ----------Hence get all the document (coins) for individual Docs delete----------
    */

    //-------------------------------  Getting document (coins) Ends  ---------------------------------------------
    final List<String> coinsFromFirestore = new ArrayList<>();

    db.collection("cryptos").document(userEmailID).collection("coin")
            .whereEqualTo("createdBy", userEmailID)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            System.out.println("Testing 1 Batch Read done" + document.getData());
                            coinsFromFirestore.add(document.getData().get("coinname").toString());
                        }

                        //-------------------------------  Getting document (coins) Ends  ---------------------------------------------


                        if(coinsFromFirestore.size()>0){

                            for (int i=0;i<coinsFromFirestore.size();i++) {

                                if ( i<(coinsFromFirestore.size()-1) ) {
                                    db.collection("cryptos").document(userEmailID).collection("coin").document(coinsFromFirestore.get(i))
                                            .delete()
                                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                    System.out.println("Testing 1 Successfully Deleted the document "  );
                                                }
                                            })
                                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                    System.out.println("Testing 1 Error Deleting the document ");
                                                }
                                            });
                                }else{  
                                    db.collection("cryptos").document(userEmailID).collection("coin").document(coinsFromFirestore.get(i))
                                            .delete()
                                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                    addTranToFireBaseeNow(db);
                                                }
                                            })
                                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) { 
                                                }
                                            });
                                    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! For last coin Ends  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            addTranToFireBaseeNow(db);
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
    //-------------------------------  Getting document (coins) Ends  ---------------------------------------------


}

private void addTranToFireBaseeNow(FirebaseFirestore db) {
    WriteBatch batch = db.batch();
    DocumentReference newCoinRef;
    //CollectionReference cryptos = db.collection("cryptos");
    List<Tran> tranList = getAllTranForFireStore();

    String firebaseUID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    for (Tran t : tranList) { 
        Map<String, Object> tranData = new HashMap<>();
        tranData.put("firebaseid", firebaseUID);
        tranData.put("createdBy", userEmailID);
        tranData.put("coinid", t.getCoinID());
        tranData.put("coinname", t.getCoinName());
        tranData.put("coinsymbol", t.getCoinSymbol());
        tranData.put("date", String.valueOf(t.getDate()));
        tranData.put("qty", String.valueOf(t.getQty()));
        tranData.put("price", String.valueOf(t.getPrice()));
        tranData.put("priceunit", String.valueOf(t.getPriceUnit()));
        newCoinRef= db.collection("cryptos").document(userEmailID).collection("coin").document(t.getCoinName());
        batch.set(newCoinRef, tranData);
    }
    batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            // ... 
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

No index is setup for my DB

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code, how you insert your data?

Comment: Added the code which inserts the data

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `set` without any options, it will overwrite the existing data. But your requirement is to merge your data, so you have to use the merge option as follows:

```
batch.set(newCoinRef, tranData, SetOptions.merge());
```

You can read more about options [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SetOptions).

Furthermore there is a good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597327/difference-between-set-with-merge-true-and-update) which lists the differences between `set`, `update` and `create`.

Comment: Even after using the SetOptions.merge() I do have only 1 record per coin..

Answer (score 0):

You can use update and change one variable

```
 reference.document("documentname").update("field", variable)
```

or

```
 reference.document("documentname").set({
    field: variable
}, { merge: true });
```

Or.. if you have to update an entire object, you can use:

```
 reference.document("documentname").set(newObject, { merge: true });
```

Check this article:
https://saveyourtime.medium.com/firebase-cloud-firestore-add-set-update-delete-get-data-6da566513b1b