# Firebase: how to add/omit a field to/from an object rather than replacing the whole object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore function where

```
admin
  .firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .doc(context.params.userId)
  .set({field1: false});
```

The problem is, this replaces the given user object with `{field1: false}`. I want to be able to add `{field1: false}` to the object while preserving all other existing fields, and also to be able to remove the `field1` field from the object if it already exists.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Do this answer your questions ? [how-to-add-new-property-to-an-object-in-cloud-firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800228/how-to-add-new-property-to-an-object-in-cloud-firestore)

Comment: Use .update() instead of .set() I guess