# Does the angularfire6 document update command fail if the document doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

The current angularfire docs (Angularfire 6.0.4, Latest commit d91965e on Mar 30 2020), says only this on manipulating documents:

> AngularFirestore provides methods for setting, updating, and deleting
> document data.
>
> set(data: T) - Destructively updates a document's data.
>
> update(data: T) - Non-destructively updates a document's data.
>
> delete() - Deletes an entire document. Does not delete any nested
> collections.

When interacting directly with Firebase (i.e. not using angularfirestore), firebase is pretty clear that an update will fail if the document does not exist; one must use the `set` operation for new documents (perhaps with the {merge: true} option as a safety catch in case the document exists).

What does the Angular Firestore `update(data: T)` command do if the document does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

`update()` will fail of the document doesn't already exist.

If you need to create-or-update in one operation that does not fail whether or not the document already exists, you should [use set() and pass { merge: true } to it as the second argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597327/difference-between-set-with-merge-true-and-update).  Or you can use a transaction to make an atomic get-and-set operation depending on what's returned by `get()`.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. However, your link goes to a comment on Firestore. I'm asking specifically about AngularFire, version 6 (my question notes the Firestore behavior). It is very possible that the AngularFire update wraps the low-level Firestore method.  Can you confirm that your answer applies to AngularFire 6.x?

Comment: Angularfire is just a wrapper around the core JavaScript SDK.  They have similar APIs.