# Firestore do not merge specific map field

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a `PUT: /users` endpoint which takes multiple fields.
In most cases I want to just call `.set` on the document with `{merge: true}` to be able to update individual document-fields without removing others. but in another case I was to update a map to only have one value within it.

for example:

```js
// user doc
displayName: 'Frank'
age: 28
gender: {
  male: true
}
orientation: {
  female: true
}
```

`displayName` & `age` are fine to be merged but when it comes to `gender` & `orientation` i want to flat-out replace the map with a new one. i know I could have a property of `gender: 'male'` but this doesn't allow for scalable querying as I am building a dating app and need to have an as flexible as possible query-base.

At the moment say I was to call `...doc.set({ gender: {female: true} }, {merge: true});`
My document structure would look like:

```js
displayName: 'Frank'
age: 28
gender: {
  male: true,
  female: true,
}
orientation: {
  female: true
}
```

But ideally it would just fully replace the `gender` map altogether. i.e

```js
displayName: 'Frank'
age: 28
gender: {
  female: true
}
orientation: {
  female: true
}
```

Has anyone any experience with this? Again I want to keep this structure as a Map so that I can run queries like

```js
db
  .collection('users')
  .where(`gender.${myOrientation}`, '==', true)
  .where('gender.all', '==', true) <-- for non-gender-specific users
```

I am also aware of the `array` structure but firestore-queries are limited to 1 array query per query.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be better to use update instead of set with merge?
Using this:

```js
      var userDoc = db.collection('users').doc(docId);
      userDoc.update({ gender: {female: true} });
```

You will get the exact result you need.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597327/difference-between-set-with-merge-true-and-update#:%7E:text=set%20without%20merge%20will%20overwrite,if%20the%20document%20already%20exists) there is a Stack Overflow thread that explains the differences between using update or set with merge in Cloud Firestore. In one answer, there is also an example about merge:true behaviour in nested fields.