# Loop to add docs to Google Firestore

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to loop through a `List` to add each item to a `google firestore doc`. However, the problem I am facing is that **ONLY the last item in the `List` is added to the doc**.

Note: The line `print("=== $i POST SUCCESSFULLY ADDED ====")` prints incremental for 5 times as expected

**QUESTION: How can I get this loop to add all items to the firestore doc?**

```html
  void addPost() {
    DocumentReference documentReferencer = _firestore.collection('posts').doc();
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
      documentReferencer.set(postsData[i]);
      print("=== $i POST SUCCESSFULLY ADDED ===="); //PRINTS 5 TIMES
      i++;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what your problem is in here, but it looks like your code is ignoring the fact that POST-ing data to a server is an `asynchronous` operation.

In other words, I'd expect that you need to `await` that to happen.

Also, I'd refactor the loop for readability.

Your code should be something like:

```
Future<void> addPost() async {
    DocumentReference documentReferencer = _firestore.collection('posts').doc();
    for(final post in postsData) {
      await documentReferencer.set(post);
      print("=== $i POST SUCCESSFULLY ADDED ===="); //PRINTS 5 TIMES
    }
  }
```

Comment: As nothing is happening after `set()` using an `async` function with `await` should not be necessary. And also because the order in which the items are written to the database does not matter using a sync call is perfectly fine.

The only issue is that the information in the print statement is wrong because at that point the item did not finish writing to the database. Also we do not know if the action was successful.

Comment: True that. Care to share more context, or code, so that I can look into it?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want to know but see my answer below for additional information to the original question. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In fact all items are written to the doc but you keep overwriting the document with the next item ending up with only the last item.

When calling [`set()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/set.html) you should use [`SetOptions`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/SetOptions-class.html) to set `merge` to `true` like so.

```
  void addPost() {
    DocumentReference documentReferencer = _firestore.collection('posts').doc();
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
      documentReferencer.set(postsData[i], SetOptions(merge: true));
      print("=== $i POST SUCCESSFULLY ADDED ===="); //PRINTS 5 TIMES
      i++;
    }
  }
```

Alternatively use [`update()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/update.html). Attention: This will fail if the document does not exist yet.

```
  void addPost() {
    DocumentReference documentReferencer = _firestore.collection('posts').doc();
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
      documentReferencer.update(postsData[i]);
      print("=== $i POST SUCCESSFULLY ADDED ===="); //PRINTS 5 TIMES
      i++;
    }
  }
```

I recommend you debugging your code step by step while keeping an eye on the database. Then you can see how you keep overwriting the doc.

Also be aware that you are not catching any errors in case the database calls go wrong. So you can't tell if the action was successful. The only thing you know at the point of your `print()` is that the request was sent to Firebase.

Further readings:

- Firebase documentation: [Add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)
- Flutter Firebase documentation: [Usage - Writing data](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#writing-data)
- Stack Overflow: [Difference between set with {merge: true} and update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46600599/12999969)