# Firestore - Does the dot notation work with set()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to run this code:

```
function updateUserLimitations(userId, limitations, batchOrTransaction = undefined) {
  const userLimitationsRef = firestore
    .collection("users")
    .doc(userId)
    .collection("limitations")
    .doc("userLimitations");

  if (batchOrTransaction) {
    return batchOrTransaction.set(
      userLimitationsRef,
      limitations,
      { merge: true }
    );
  }

  return userLimitationsRef.set(limitations, { merge: true });
}
```

> updateUserLimitations(userId, { "messages.totalMessages": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) });

But...

Instead of getting this doc data in my db:

```
{ // Doc data
   messages: {
      initialDate: timestamp, // Date of the first message (I need to preserve it),
      totalMessages: 20,
   },
}
```

I am getting:

```
{
   ...other doc data...,
   messages.totalMessages: 20,
}
```

I need the set with the merge option, because I am updating **and creating if the doc doesn't exist...**.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Hi. Dot notation only works for maps. "message.totalMesssages" is not a map. You should do something like: ``{ message: {} } message['totalMessages'] = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)``. Also, Why using this when you're applying ``merge: true``? If you're using merge, you could directly write ``{ message: { totalMessages: 'yourValue' } }``

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero does { merge: true } work for updating a specific field of an object too? I thought it was only possible via dot notation.

Comment: What does `limitations` contain? Show us the value.

Comment: @AlexMamo I updated the question with the value

Comment: I think this could be useful to you @VictorMolina https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597327/difference-between-set-with-merge-true-and-update

Comment: okay it works with the current answer. Didn't know that set combined with { merge: true } merges objects fields too, I thought it only merged the doc top level fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an object for "setting" nested data:

```
{
  messages: {
    totalMessages: 20,
  }
}
```

The "dot" notation is for applying updates to nested data.

Comment: The object itself has more data. I am using the dot notation for updating a specific field. BTW, I will try it, but I think that the object will be overlapped, instead of updating the specific field.

Comment: my fault, it deeply update object fields too.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only to update, then use the [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) function instead of `set()`. So please change the following line of code:

```
return userLimitationsRef.set(limitations, { merge: true });
```

To:

```
return userLimitationsRef.update(limitations);
```

And your:

```
updateUserLimitations(userId, { "messages.totalMessages": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) });
```

It will work as expected. If you want to add if it doesn't exist, then you should indeed use the [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) function.

Comment: The main problem is that I need to create the doc if doesn't exist, as I specified at the bottom of the question.  BTW, without the dot notation, it seems that I can deeply update the object combining set() with { merge: true } too!

Comment: @AlexMamo: The `update()` function does not take write options Alex and can (last I checked) not be used to *create* a document. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Didn't see that "creating if the doc doesn't exist". Of course, the update function does not contain a second argument. Forgot to remove when copied and paste it. As the name says, it updates, if a document exists. Doesn't create documents.

Answer (score 1):

With my current implementation

```
function updateUserLimitations(userId, limitations, batchOrTransaction = undefined) {
  const userLimitationsRef = firestore
    .collection("users")
    .doc(userId)
    .collection("limitations")
    .doc("userLimitations");

  if (batchOrTransaction) {
    return batchOrTransaction.set(
      userLimitationsRef,
      limitations,
      { merge: true }
    );
  }

  return userLimitationsRef.set(limitations, { merge: true });
}
```

I can deeply update the document messages field too, as follows:

```
updateUserLimitations(
   userId,
   { 
      messages: {
        totalMessages: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
      }
   }
);
```

It preserves all the previous existing object fields and updates the specific one.

```
{ // Doc data
  messages: {
    initialDate: timestamp, // PRESERVED!
    totalMessages: 21,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mergeFields`.

For example:

```
const newBook = { id: '', name: 'Some book' };

docRef.set(
    {`books.${newBook.id}`: newBook},
    { mergeFields: [`books.${newBook.id}`] }
);
```

This way you only set the `books.${newBook.id}` field value.

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.SetOptions#optional-mergefields