# Is it possible to store a user id as the key of a field in a Firestore document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I saw this in the ["Get to know Firestore"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXbHa.png) youtube series from the official Firebase channel, where they used a userId as the key of a field. However, I can't seem to recreate this in my project using  "firebase": "^9.6.6", and angular 13.0.4.

```
private async addMemberToGroupDetail(groupId: string) {
const groupRef = doc(this.firestore, 'groupDetail', groupId);
const userId = this.authService.userId;
updateDoc(groupRef, {
     roles: {
       `${userId}`: 'member',
     },
});
```

}

Error: Property assignment expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this syntax a shot:

```
updateDoc(groupRef, {
     roles: {
       [`${userId}`]: 'member',
     },
});
```

Might just need those square brackets as assigning the key dynamically.

As @Frank added in comments, if you don't need to convert to string, you can just do:

```
[userId]: 'member'
```

Comment: That should work indeed, or a bit simpler `[userId]: 'member'`