# how to add new data to existing map in firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

**here is the firebase document data**

[image]

I want to add a new map value to the `purchased-id`. this is the current code

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userID).set({
  'purchased-id': {
    widget.head: widget.id,
  }
});
```

but with this code the map value is replaced,
how do I add another map value to the existing map

like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need `merge: true` to update the map with its new value.

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userID).set({
  'purchased-id': {
    widget.head: widget.id,
  }
}, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects

Also to differentiate with `.set` and `.update`, have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47554197/11566161

Comment: `widget.head: widget.id`, how can i use the template string instead of  `widget.id`

Comment: If you are asking about [string interpolation in dart](https://dart.dev/language/built-in-types#strings), then it same as assigning above: `widget.head: "Key: ${widget.id}"`

Comment: No, I mean in js.